# show only the beginnning of articles in the home page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want my wordpress theme to only show a few lines of the articles in the home page, and then some dots (ellipses) at the end with a "read more" link. How can this be done? I'm using the Elegant Grunge 1.0.3 theme right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) function to do what you want. I don't know your theme but may be it have an option to do it.